# VBScript works in Windows 7 Professional, not in Windows Home Premium

Tags: vbscript, zip, admin, uac

What my script does is, first it checks to see if any archived event files in C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs are older than 7 days. If they are it deletes them.

The second thing that it does is any remaining Archive*.evtx files (ones that are newer than 7 days) it will zip up and send to whatever path you specify.

Now my problem lies with the fact that my desktop runs Windows 7 professional and the script was running 100% correct last night while I was putting the finishing touches on it. Now my laptop runs Windows Home Premium, so at work today when trying to run the script from my laptop all of a sudden it does not work.

It will make the zip file in the correct path but it will not actually put anything in the zip file.

Now at home I had to run the script as administrator to get it to work, which required me to make a registry edit that I found online to even add the "Run as administrator" button when you right click a .vbs file. (Wierd that this isn't there already but whatever)

So I made the same edit on my laptop, tried to run it again, and same thing happened. Empty zip file in the correct path.

So next I figured that something was up with the UAC messing around with it. So I turned off the UAC on my laptop and then ran as administrator but it still ran into the same problem. At home my UAC is still turned on and the script works so I am not sure at all what the issue is.

Then I thought maybe on my laptop I was having a permissions problem with the C: drive or something odd like that. So I opened cmd as admin and ran a "takeown" to make sure that the drive was allowed to be accessed by admin.

Then went and ran the script again, still ran into the same problem.

I'm about out of ideas now of why it will not run, when I get home from work I am going to try it on my desktop again and see if it still works. (It should, I've made no changes to the script)

If anyone could help me out here that would be amazing. I was hoping to have this all done by today and set up as a scheduled task so it would start running but it seems to want to cause me some more issues.

The script is found below:

---

```
Option Explicit

Dim oFSO, oFolder, sDirectoryPath, sDestinationPath, sOutputFilename, Shell, sFileExt,     sFilePrefix
Dim oFileCollection, oFile, sDir 
Dim iDaysOld 


Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'Specify Directory Path From Where You want to clear the old files 'Also where you want destination for zip
sDirectoryPath = "C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\"
sDestinationPath = "C:\Script\files\outzips\"
sOutputFilename = shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%COMPUTERNAME%")
sFileExt = ".evtx"
sFilePrefix = "Archive*"
' Specify Number of Days Old File to Delete
iDaysOld = 7

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sDirectoryPath) 
Set oFileCollection = oFolder.Files 

For each oFile in oFileCollection
'Specify the Extension of file that you want to delete 'and the number with Number of character in the file extension
If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = ".evtx" Then

    If oFile.DateLastModified < (Date() - iDaysOld) Then 
    oFile.Delete(True) 
    End If 

End If   
Next 



Set oFSO = Nothing 
Set oFolder = Nothing 
Set oFileCollection = Nothing 
Set oFile = Nothing 




Dim Command, RetVal
Dim d : d = Date() 
Dim dateStr : dateStr = Year(d) & "-" & Right("00" & Month(d), 2) & "-" & Right("00" &     Day(d), 2)
Dim t : t = Time()
Dim timeStr: timeStr = Hour(t) & "-" & Right("00" & Minute(t), 2) & "-" & Right("00" & Second(t), 2)



Command = """C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe"" a  " & sDestinationPath & sOutputFilename & "-" & dateStr & "-" & timeStr & ".zip " & sDirectoryPath & sFilePrefix & sFileExt


        RetVal = Shell.Run(Command,0,true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahum.. could it be there are no files like Archive*.evtx in your folder C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs ? Normally there aren't and i suppose that on your desktop for any reason there are so the script works there.
Try to put a wscript.echo after command = "...." and try to run this at the console. There it's easier to find out why the command doesn't run and if it runs chances are high it will run in your script also.

Comment: I wish this was the case. I made sure to save an event file starting with Archive before I started this process so that it would find something. Going to look at it again tomorrow since its the weekend and haven't tried to fix it yet.